# Initial value for django model autofield

Tags: django, django-models, auto-increment

I'm creating an app in django that will eventually be filled with data from its predecessor. I'd like to have certain models start their auto-increment counter at 10000 to differentiate this data in advance and keep the pk accounting consistant. How can I do this in the model? AutoField doesn't seem to take parameters that would let me do this.

Comment: I ended up creating a post_syncdb signal that checks for different database types(`if 'mysql' in connection.settings_dict['ENGINE']`) and  handles resetting autoincrement for each table. The sqlite is one is pretty ugly, but there you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a question about Django. AutoField is simply a representation of the underlying database's autoincrement property, and Django doesn't control it. Depending on your database backend, you might be able to reset the autoincrement start value: look at your db's documentation for details.

Comment: My hope was to be able to do this through the ORM, to keep out of backend-specifics.

Comment: As Django has an ORM, e.g. a layer that abstracts the underlying database, it **is** a Django question. Unfortunately, the answer is "there's no built-in support for this". This question explains workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117800/how-to-get-django-autofields-to-start-at-a-higher-number