# Django ORM cannot auto set primary key for model after loading data from legacy db

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I'm working with a new Django project which need to load data from a legacy db, but saving new model object always fails with `IntegrityError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint` after I loaded data from the legacy db.

Primary key in legacy db is in range from 10000 to 200000, the new db is Postgres 9.5 and never manual set SQL schema on it.

My model could be simple like:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

This will fails when I run `MyModel().save()` or `MyModel.create()`. It's OK to run `MyModel(id=233).save()` like I used at loading data.

I guess it's because it does not know where to start to auto generate primary key from. How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add an auto-increment field in django, you are supposed to use [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

You should define your `id` field like this:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

If you want to name it as `id`, you are not required to define the field, django does that for you.

A model without explicit `id` field will still have a AutoField `id` as a primary key.

Comment: After migrating, this works. But the doc says this is the default behavior, does this means I don't need to define `id` field manually?

Comment: Another question, If I want key `id` starts from 300000, what should I do?

Comment: Yes, django adds `id` AutoField by default. You don't need to add manually if you wish to name it as `id`.

Comment: You can change that at DB level. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117800/how-to-get-django-autofields-to-start-at-a-higher-number

Comment: Emm, maybe better to add it in migration files, so every developer in my team will gets the convenient. Really helps, thanks!