# How to make auto increment field in django which starts from 10000

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I want to make an auto increment field in Django which starts from bigger value , I found use **Autofield** in models but It starts from 1 .

```
class University(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    university_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    university_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.university_name
```

How can do this ? Any helpful suggestion will be appreciated ?

Comment: Take a look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117800/how-to-get-django-autofields-to-start-at-a-higher-number since you appear to be using mysql

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to catch the [post migrate signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-migrate)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate

def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
     if sender.name = 'myapp'
     try:
         university = University.objects.create(pk=999, ...)
         university.delete()
     except IntegrityError:
         pass

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    ...

    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(my_callback, sender=self)
```

What we are doing here is creating a record and deleting it immediately. On mysql that changes the next value in the auto increment. It doesn't matter that the record has been deleted. The next asigned number will be 1000.

Comment: I like this solution but I cannot get it to work.  I added the code to `apps.py`, made a small change to my models and did `makemigrations` and `migrate` but it is not creating new records from 1000.  What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think this works with SQLite, does it? No matter how many records you had previously, if you delete them all and your table is empty, it will assign 1 as primary key to the first record created. @HenryM was probably using SQLite. Did anyone ever find a solution to this question though?

Comment: This was not tagged as sqlite. Might i also suggest that you actually try it on sqlite

Answer (score -1):

Rather then trying in front end , I suggest you to create sequences in backend (in Database) with starting higher numbers Sequence value.

Hope this will solve your purposes.