# Django starting id field from 1000

Tags: django

I would like to start my ids on a django model from 1000.  I've found this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778600/how-to-make-auto-increment-field-in-django-which-starts-from-10000) on Stackoverflow but I am missing something in my implementation because it is not working.

This is my code in `apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate
from django.db import IntegrityError

from invoice.models import Invoice

def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    if sender.name =="invoice":
        try:
            Invoice.objects.create(id=999)
            Invoice.objects.delete()
        except IntegrityError:
            pass

class InvoiceConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'invoice'

    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(my_callback, sender=self)
```

I've then ensure `migrate` takes place but the model continues to increment from low numbers.  What am I missing?

Comment: Most databases each time when booting calculate the *maximum* id in the database and then increment from that part on. So in case you reboot the database, and no such invoice is present, it starts iterating from `0`.

Comment: It will work if you do not *reboot* the database server typically (since as long as the database is *active*, it stores the ID dispatcher in memory), but there are no guarantees how IDs are dispatched when a database reboots. Typically this should not be your problem either. If you really need something else, I propose to write an extra column, where you implement some sort of dispatcher yourself.

Comment: In short: this is something you typically can *not* control (in general). Specific databases like PostgreSQL however allow one to define a *sequence*, so then you have more control.