# How to reset_sequence to default id field sequence in DjangoModelFactory

Tags: django, django-models, factory-boy

With a factory like:

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

The model's `id` field will by default start at 1. **I want the id to start at a higher number, eg 50000.**

Using `UserFactory.reset_sequence(50000)` does not work
 unless you add this line in the factory

```
id = factory.Sequence(lambda n: n)
```

I have a lot of tests that depend on the default id increment behavior so this way is a no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I could find is by creating a `User` object starting at 49999

```
if not UserFactory.objects.filter(id=49999).exists():
    UserFactory(49999)
```

Now you can do

```
print(UserFactory().id)
>>> 50000
```

Now if your model's id is an autofield, you'll likely have to alter the underlying database schema, or resort to the `reset_sequence` method. [How to get Django AutoFields to start at a higher number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117800/how-to-get-django-autofields-to-start-at-a-higher-number)