# How to make id (primary key) of new created objects start from some value?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have an existing django model in my project, and it's already in production database (PostgreSQL) and has records in it.

And what I basically want is to set `id` (autoincrement pk) of new created objects to have at least 5 digits and start from 5.
So for example if I have last record in database with id `1924` I want my next object to have id
`51925` (last id + 1 + 50000).
So it will be like this:

```
older objects
...
1921
1922
1923
1924 # last in production
51925 # next object to be created must autoincrement from 50001 + previous id
51926
51927
.... and so on
```

Is it possible and what is the best way to do it?
thanks

Comment: Use [`ALTER SEQUENCE ... RESTART WITH <yournumber>;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118402/16361). You need to query for the previous max ID on your own, there's no syntax for saying 'start this sequence from the result of the expression "select max(id)+50000 from table"'.

Comment: @AdamKG thanks, so the previous records will still have existing ids? And only new ones will start from number I will specify?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @AdamGK comment I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14589706/10103803) that helps to generate needed psql command:

`python manage.py sqlsequencereset yourappname`

After running it, I found line with model i needed (I changed app and model names for the sake of example):

`SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"yourappname_modelname"','id'), coalesce(max("id"), 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "yourappname_modelname";`

and then just changed it to (max id + 50000):

`SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"yourappname_modelname"','id'), coalesce(max("id") + 50000, 1), max("id") IS NOT null) FROM "yourappname_modelname";`

And it worked like a charm!